# php array dereference in if statement expression

Tags: php, arrays, brackets, curly-braces

Why do I need to do array indexing using curly braces inside an if statement expression?
Why is the following illegal?

```
$birthday = "1990-01-18";
$date_birth = explode("-", $birthday);
if ($date_birth[1] != "00" && $date_birth[2] != "00") {
    $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_birth[1], 10));
    echo "$monthName $date_birth[2]";
}
```

However, the following works fine:

```
$birthday = "1990-01-18";
$date_birth = explode("-", $birthday);
if ($date_birth{1} != "00" && $date_birth{2} != "00") {
    $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_birth[1], 10));
    echo "$monthName $date_birth[2]";
}
```

Comment: Both seem to work http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7228bf53485ff759fa17d61ca900768d74a9a162 and the first version is the "proper" one.

Answer (score 1):

The two versions are exactly equivalent, [as shown here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7228bf53485ff759fa17d61ca900768d74a9a162).

Also, the [php manual page on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) states that:

> Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. `$array[42]` and `$array{42}` will both do the same thing [...])